# Pytesseract PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied, double slashes, administrator not working, image not open elsewhere

Tags: python, python-tesseract

```
import pyautogui
import keyboard
from PIL import ImageGrab
import numpy as np
import os
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = "C:\\users\\adamf\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python312\\lib\\site-packages\\"

def take_screenshot(region):
    screenshot = ImageGrab.grab(region)
    return screenshot

if True:
    question = 170,345,770,400
    screenshot = take_screenshot(question)
    screenshot_path = 'questionss.png'
    screenshot.save(screenshot_path)
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(screenshot_path))
    os.remove(screenshot_path)
    print(extracted_text)
```

When I run my Code I get a Permission Error on pytesseract:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\adamf\Desktop\import pyautogui.py", line 20, in <module>
    extracted_text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open(screenshot_path))
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 423, in image_to_string
    return {
           ^
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 426, in <lambda>
    Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 288, in run_and_get_output      
    run_tesseract(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 255, in run_tesseract
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd_args, **subprocess_args())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\adamf\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

It seemed like a common issue, and double backslashes should've resolved it.

However, as you can see- Ive tried double backslashes and running as administrator yet it gives me the same error.

Comment: `tesseract_cmd` must be the path of the actual tesseract executable, not just the folder that contains it.  It's trying to execute a directory, and of course that's not allowed.  The executable is probably not installed in your site-packages.